# Long.decode and Long.parseLong

Tags: java, long-integer, hex

In a test I see that `Long.decode` work similar to `Long.parseLong` for simple number format strings (i mean strings without `'0x'` ,...).

```
System.out.println(Long.decode("123") + Long.decode("123"));  // prints  246
System.out.println(Long.parseLong("123") + Long.parseLong("123")); // same as above
```

can I use `Long.decode` instead of `Long.parseLong` anywhere? if not why?

Comment: Read the two specs very carefully.  In particular, note the capitalization (or not) of the word "long".

Comment: @HotLicks other than the return value (Long, long) is there any diff?

Comment: Read the specs.  That should be the first thing you do when you have any questions about a Java API function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They will both act similarly, but `Long.parseLong` returns a primitive `long` whereas `Long.decode` returns a new `Long` object, which takes more time and resources. So, it's probably best to use `Long.parseLong` for simple cases. But, `Long.decode` provides more flexibility as it will allow you to decode inputs that are hex (e.g. 0xFFFF), or octal (e.g. 010 == 8).

Comment: Perhaps you meant `hex (e.g. 0xFFFF), or octal (e.g. 010 == 8).`

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction. Had a brain fart. Edited into my answer

Answer (score 6):

You can't use decode() if your numbers might start with a 0 and you don't want this to be octal.

e.g.

```
Integer.decode("010") == 8 // octal
Integer.parseInt("010") == 10 // always decimal
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, as you have noted they can be used interchangeably for decimal values, but there are a few differences:

[Long.parseLong(s, radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong-java.lang.String-int-) has an overridden implementation that also allows you to specify a radix, e.g. `16` for hexadecimal values. In contrast, the [Long.decode(s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#decode-java.lang.String-) allows you to specify a decodable string.

Compare:

```
long first = Long.parseLong("10", 16);
Long second = Long.decode("0x10");
```

Here both `first` and `second` will have the decimal value of `16`. However, as noted in the comment, `parseLong()` returns a primitive `long` value, whereas `decode()` returns a `Long` object.

Comment: A `long` and a `Long` cannot be used "interchangeably", even with auto-boxing.

Comment: Ah, the return types differ.

Comment: @HotLicks I've added a clarification, both with regards to the usages, as well as to the return values.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between these two methods is that with the `decode` method you can pass octal and hexadecimal strings in addition to decimal strings. The single parameter version of the `parseLong` method only interprets strings representing signed decimal integers.

So you can use decode but in your case, if it just to parse decimal number it is better to use the `parseLong` method.

Comment: why it's better to use parseLong?

Comment: @طاهر: because it does what you seem to want, i.e. parse a decimal number. If you don't expect tghe string to contain octal or hexadecimal numbers, but only decimal numbers, then use parseLong. If you expect the string to contain octal or hexadecimal numbers, then use decode.

Comment: It needs less resources and it may be faster.

Answer (score 0):

The output should be equivalent, but looking at the source, `Long.parseLong()` may be faster. `Long.decode()` does some comparisons with `String.startsWith()` to determine if the value is octal, hex, decimal etc. `Long.parseLong()` only does a few comparisons with `String.charAt()`. If you are worried about performance, it may be worth testing both to see which does better.